# Synchronize content of directories in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command

Let's assume I have following source directory

```
source/
    subdir1/file1
    subdir1/file2
    subdir2/file3
    subdir3/file4
```

and target directory

```
target
    subdir1/file5
    subdir2/file6
    subdir4/file7
```

I would like to move content of source subdirectories to right target subdirectories so result look like this

```
target
    subdir1/file1
    subdir1/file2    
    subdir1/file5
    subdir2/file6
    subdir2/file3
    subdir3/file4
    subdir4/file7
```

Is there some Linux command to do this or must I write a script myself?

Comment: Have you looked at `man cp` or `man rsync`?

Comment: @John1024 I do not want to copy files I want to move them. This is important because volume of files is big.

Comment: In that case, see `man mv`.  The word "synchronize" usually means to keep two copies up to date with each other.  You might want to rephrase.

Comment: @John1024 Although, `rsync` does have options to affect `mv` semantics  as well...

Comment: @John1024 mv does not allow such functionality. If you are going to post uninformed comments or advices to use man or google you better remain silent because you do not provide any value.

Comment: Interesting.  You are right about `mv` having problems with merging directories.  I wrote a fix for you below.  Let me know.  P.S. Apologies for being terse.

Answer (score 1):

To suimmarize, it is important to move, not copy.  That rules out `cp` and `rsync` but allows `mv`.  `mv`, however, has the issue that it is not good at merging the old directory into the new.

In the examples that you gave, the target directory had the complete directory tree but lacked files.  If that is the case, try:

```
cd /source ; find . -type f -exec  sh -c 'mv "$1" "/target/$1"' _  {} \;
```

The above starts by selecting the source as the current directory with `cd /source`.  Next, we use `find` which is the usual *nix utility for finding files/directories.  In this case, give `find`  the `-type f` option to tell it to look only for files.  With the `-exec` option, we tell it to move any such files found to the target directory.

You have choices for how to deal with conflicts between the two directory trees.  You can give `mv` the `-f` option and it will overwrite files in the target without asking, or you can give it the `-n` option and it will never overwrite a target file, or your can give it the `-i` option and it will ask you each time.

#### In case the target directory tree is incomplete

If the target directory tree is missing some directories that are in the source, the we have to create them on the fly.  This adds just minor complication:

```
cd /source ; find . -type f -exec  sh -c 'mkdir -p "/target/${1%/*}"; mv "$1" "/target/$1"' _  {} \;
```

The `mkdir -p` command assures that the directory we want exists before we try to move the file there.

#### Additional notes

- The form `${1%/*}` is an example of one of the shells powerful features called "parameter expansion".  This particular feature is suffix removal.  In general, it looks like `${parameter%word}` which tells bash to expand `word` and remove it from the end of `parameter`.  In our case, the name of the parameter is `1`, meaning the first argument to the script.  We want to remove the file name and just leave behind the directory that the file is in.  So, the word `/*` tells the shell to remove the last slash and any characters which follow.
- The commands above use both single and double quotes.  They have to be copied exactly for the command to work properly.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't expect any script. I wanted to know whether there is already some command. I see that there is not so probably your script or some simple Python script is best solution. I have question though. What does ${1%/*} bash expansion means?

Comment: @Trismegistos That is called suffix removal.  I added a discussion of it.

Answer (score 0):

To sync dorectory maybe used rsync

Example:

```
rsync -avzh source/ target/
```

More info [man rsync](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync)

Move (no copy)

```
rsync --remove-source-files -avzh source/ target/
```

Comment: What I want is to move the files not copy them. Copying is to slow and they are laying on same physical disc.

Comment: Just modify command to rsync --remove-source-files -avzh source/ target/

Comment: Does it really move files or it copies them and than delete?

Comment: Rsync does not move files. It copies them and then deletes them. This is time consuming operation and it is not how moving on a single disc works.